# Is DTM2000 density model expecting adjusted or observed solar flux?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, atmospheric-drag, astrodynamics, propagation

I know two models to calculate the atmosphere density during a satellite orbit propagation. The two models are NRLMSISE-00 and DTM-2000. To feed the models I'm using Space Weather Data provided by Celestrak (https://celestrak.org/SpaceData/SW-Last5Years.txt). I was surprised the see that both adjusted and observed data are provided in this file. I found that observed data must be used for NRLMSISE-00 model. However, I didn't see any information about which type of data to use (i.e., adjusted or observed) for DTM-2000. Does anyone have the answer or a reference?